# How to kill a child process started by batch in java?

Tags: java, batch-file, process

In the code below, a Java process is launched by

```
ProcessBuilder pb = ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C","java.bat");
Process p = pb.start();
```

When p.destroy(), the process started from java.bat still running. How to terminate this process in java?

Comment: you can kill it using taskill e.g.

ProcessBuilder killer = ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe","taskkill /im java.bat /f");
killer.start();

Comment: @JawadZeb that kills the batch process, not the child process.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643762/terminate-child-processes-spawned-by-a-processbuilder-on-nix  - maybe similar methods work on windows

Comment: By adding the /t will kills the whole tree including the java.bat .Or if  the child process name is known then java.bat can be replaced with the process name. e.g java.bat is replaced by child.exe